# this script work good until he stop and show errore

Tags: python, mysql

```
error line : psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "cx3_fidelityinsurance.fresh_us_gmail_1" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from cx3_fidelityinsurance.fresh_us_gmail_1
```

```
import psycopg2




class database_admin():

    def __init__(self):
        self.password="pass"
        self.port = "5432"
        self.database = "ass_system"
        self.user = "user"
        self.host = "ip"

    def connect(self):
        ass_lists = psycopg2.connect(user=self.user,password=self.password,host=self.host,port=self.port,database=self.database)
        cursor = ass_lists.cursor()
        return cursor


class database_data():

    def __init__(self):
        self.password="pass"
        self.port = "5432"
        self.database = "ass_lists"
        self.user = "user"
        self.host = "ip"

    def connect(self):
        ass_lists = psycopg2.connect(user=self.user,password=self.password,host=self.host,port=self.port,database=self.database)
        cursor = ass_lists.cursor()
        return cursor


class download_database():

    def __init__(self):
        admin = database_admin()
        self.cursur_lists = admin.connect()
        data = database_data()
        self.cursur_data = data.connect()


    def download_all_lists(self):
        query_list = "select * from admin.data_lists"
        self.cursur_lists.execute(query_list)
        rows = self.cursur_lists.fetchall() 
        for row in rows:
            query_list = "select * from "+ row[1]
            self.cursur_data.execute(query_list)
            rows_data = self.cursur_data.fetchall() 
            for row_data in rows_data:
                print(row[1])
                f=open(row[1],'a+')
                f.write(row_data[1]+'\n')
                f.close()

def main():
    data =download_database()
    data.download_all_lists()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You sure this is code causing this error? As `fresh_us_gmail_1` seams never to be used.. But i assume `fresh_us_gmail_1` is been defined as table data in `admin.data_lists`?

Comment: yes i think cuz this shema.table is empty there is no fresh_us_gmail_1 on cx3_fidelityinsurance

Answer (score 0):

this part of your code is susceptible of query injection you should not make RAW SQL queries like this

```
def download_all_lists(self):
    query_list = "select * from admin.data_lists"#never do this...sql injection
    self.cursur_lists.execute(query_list)
    rows = self.cursur_lists.fetchall() 
    for row in rows:
        query_list = "select * from "+ row[1]#never do this...sql injection
        self.cursur_data.execute(query_list)
        rows_data = self.cursur_data.fetchall() 
        for row_data in rows_data:
            print(row[1])#you can print row[1] once 
            f=open(row[1],'a+')#this is bad...don't need to open row[1] here
            f.write(row_data[1]+'\n')
            f.close()
```

but do SQL QUERIES as in the following code [see modifications]

```
def download_all_lists(self):
    tb_cl = sql.Identifier('admin.data_lists')
    self.cursur_lists.execute('SELECT * FROM %s'%tb_cl)
    rows = self.cursur_lists.fetchall() 
    for row in rows:
        tb_cl=sql.Identifier(row[1])
        self.cursur_data.execute('SELECT * FROM %s'%tb_cl)
        rows_data = self.cursur_data.fetchall() 
        print(row[1])
        with open(row[1], 'a+') as f:#with will take care of closing f when leaving it
            for row_data in rows_data:
                f.write(row_data[1]+'\n')
```

About your error some column name are not defined in the schema (may table too). globaly check all your schema

Comment: that's fine in this precisely context but it is ever a bad idea to do this like this way.

Comment: You need to do something more like using `format(sql.Identifier('...')` like the manual [explains](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) on the **second** query as `query_list = "select * from admin.data_lists"` is safe it is not SQL injectable as the SQL statement is not dynamically build from untrusted data sources..

Comment: we do impossible but the script download only 39 file it should download 3800 file

Answer (score 0):

import psycopg2

class database_admin():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.password="pass"
    self.port = "5432"
    self.database = "ass_system"
    self.user = "user"
    self.host = "ip"

def connect(self):
    ass_lists = psycopg2.connect(user=self.user,password=self.password,host=self.host,port=self.port,database=self.database)
    cursor = ass_lists.cursor()
    return cursor
```

class database_data():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.password="pass"
    self.port = "5432"
    self.database = "ass_lists"
    self.user = "user"
    self.host = "ip"

def connect(self):
    ass_lists = psycopg2.connect(user=self.user,password=self.password,host=self.host,port=self.port,database=self.database)
    cursor = ass_lists.cursor()
    return cursor
```

class download_database():

```
def __init__(self):
    admin = database_admin()
    self.cursur_lists = admin.connect()
    data = database_data()
    self.cursur_data = data.connect()


def download_all_lists(self):
    query_list = "select * from admin.data_lists"
    self.cursur_lists.execute(query_list)
    rows = self.cursur_lists.fetchall() 
    for row in rows:
        query_list = "select * from "+ row[1]
        try:
            self.cursur_data.execute(query_list)
            rows_data = self.cursur_data.fetchall() 
            for row_data in rows_data:
                print(row[1])
                f=open(row[1],'a+')
                f.write(row_data[1]+'\n')
                f.close()
        except:
            print("skip~")
```

def main():

```
data =download_database()
data.download_all_lists()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()